# adding additionl header to the table without jquery table sorter inteferring

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tablesorter

I need to add an additional header to the top of the table. the purpose is to just to tell what the table is about. therefore I do not need any sorting in it. But the problem is the jquery tablesorter interferes with it since I am adding it inside the tablesorter class.
here is my code so far:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

        jQuery("table").tablesorter({ 


    }); 

    });
    </script>
        puts "<table cellspacing=\"1px\" class=\"tablesorter\" >"
        puts "<thead>"
        puts "<tr>"
        puts    "<th>Search</th>"
        puts    "<th>Sub-App</th>"
        puts    "<th>Division</th>"

        puts "</tr>"
        puts "</thead>"
        puts "<tbody>"

        puts "<tr>"
        puts    "<td>$level</td>"
        puts    "<td>$div_name</td>"
        puts    "<td>$reg_name</td>"

        puts "</tr>"

        puts "</tbody>"
        puts "</table>"
```

Here is what i want to add

```
            puts "<table cellspacing=\"1px\" class=\"tablesorter\" >"
            puts "<thead>"
            puts "<tr><th>Search Division/Region</th></tr>
            puts "<tr>"
            puts    "<th>Search</th>"
            # and so on
            puts    "<th>Sub-App</th>"
```

Can I get some solution to do the above without breaking the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first row is just missing a `colspan="3"`. Try using this HTML ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/vCTHw/160/)):

```
<thead>
    <tr><th colspan="3">Search Division/Region</th></tr>
    <tr><th>Search</th><th>Sub-App</th><th>Division</th></tr>
</thead>
```

then disable the first header cell by setting the sorter to false:

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    headers : {
        0 : { sorter: false }
    },
    widgets: ['zebra']
});
```